# Wix UI - UIText Table Missing

Tags: user-interface, wix

I'm new to Wix and Installer Files so forgive me if this is a simple fix

I'm creating my own custom UI just for getting use to the software and trying out new things.

I've currently created a new Dialog which will have the Feature Tree, however for the item size and location I seem to be getting the error message !!UIText Table Missing!!

This is the same as the Disk Usage dialog, screenshots below;

[image: Error Message]

[image: Disk Usage]

Any idea's as to what I have done wrong?

I can update this question with code if needed

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the reason for this is that I was missing a UIRef ID

I inputted the following;

```html
 <UIRef Id ="WixUI_Common"/>
```

And that solved the problem!